# Prevent users from tampering with the view's increment code

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a function that is called when the user clicked an image. I am counting those clicks and increment the views on the server in database. The function calls a webservice that updates the views columns in the database.

I want to be able to predict when the function is called in a legit way after the user interacted with that image and clicked on it. I know that it's easy to mimic the click behavior on client side and can't be prevented. I also don't want to keep a track on the server for each IP and the image Id.

Is there any good way which is low on resources that I'll be able to prevent users from tampering with that view increment code? I have no log-in option for users, the users are all anonymous to the website.

Code sample:

```
$(document).on("click", ".the-image", function(event){
    var imageId = parseInt($(this).attr("image-id"), 10);
    // webservice to increment the views of the image +1
    $.ajax({
       url: CONST_WEBSERVICE_URL,
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       method: "POST",
       data: "{'imageId': " + imageId + "}"
   });
});
```

I built my site using ASP.NET 4.5 / C# / jQuery.

Comment: How can we possibly know when you haven't provided even a single line of code for us to know what you are doing and what is being sent. Are you using CSRF protection? What currently triggers the ajax? Question is far too broad

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the question with code

Comment: would definitely want to use csrf protection, I could copy that request and send it every second from another server

Comment: @charlietfl lol, you scare me, but true. I am looking what is csrf protection

Comment: Not something I would do personally...just have to think the way people that want to tamper with your site do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to think out of the box here. You could store the number of times the image has been clicked in the session and access the Session State within your service. Then you know if they have viewed the image already.

```
[WebMethod (EnableSession=true)]
```

Maybe then you could set a limit to the number of rows inserted into the database.

Comment: I thought about that, but this means storing data for each ID for each user that visits the site. It might be the only realy way to solve this problem, but I am eager for my app to utilize the lowest resources. I vote for this one, but waiting for more answers.

Comment: I thought about storing it in a List<int> for the sessions variable, and checking if the value already exists. Is this the way that you meant?

Comment: No, In my head I thought: `Session["ImageID"] = Session["ImageID"] += 1;` You would have to handle the session variable being a 0 the first time it was clicked though

Comment: Is it utilizes less resources than List<int>?

Comment: I would go for a `Dictionary<int, int>` The first being the imageID and the latter being the number of times it has been clicked.

Comment: But I don't need to count it as I want to allow single vote per session

Comment: I see, in that case a `List<int>` would be fine

Comment: I'm excepting your answer because it's the most useful one in my opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to set a cookie, or use local storage from your JavaScript. Unfortunately this is pretty easy to defeat (just erase the cookie or the storage element).

Binding a response to an IP address (which you don't want to do) isn't tamper proof either. One can just use a proxy server. Even if you could get some sort of absolutely unique per machine identifier this could be defeated by spinning up a bunch of virtual machines or containers.

The most you can hope for in your scenario is to be able to defeat someone casually trying to game your system.

Comment: Hi Robert, I thought about this, but this is easy to temper with.

Answer (score 0):

What about tracking the user that clicked the image? you could detect if it is a crawler and if so you don't increase the count.

You can get a list of crawler IP Addresses and also you can use the user agent to track them. Here you can get a list of user agents that are marked as bots: http://www.user-agents.org/ and here you have a list IP addresses that are used by bots: http://www.jafsoft.com/searchengines/webbots.html

Comment: When I deal with people that mimick a real use, I won't be able to identify the attack by examining the user agents from my understanding.

Comment: If it is a bot you can catch it. If it is a single person, you won't be able to catch it because he's not a bot. But the question is, is a single person going to mimick a click? why don't he just click on the image instead of mimicking it? Using the IP Address, user agent and time could help you detect if it is the same person clicking over an over and you could combine it with a cookie/localStorage. There's no perfect solution, you need to combine different approaches.

Comment: I agree that different approaches is the way to go. Right now I checked if the triger is undefined or not, If it's defined, it's not a bot. Second, I took Jack idea to also implement it on Session, but looking for what others have to say. Maybe someone comes with another good method.

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger is undefined"? also consider that the session can be cleared programatically.

Comment: I mean that if the user uses jQuery .trigger() function to trigger a click manually in the console, I can identify it as a none legit click. If it runs using trigger(), the event for the callback function will be 'undefined', not an object.

Comment: But you are just sending the imageId to the server, I don't get what you mean by event is undefined. They can call your AJAX function from the console and you'll get the imageId at server-side without knowing if it was from console or by clicking the image.

Comment: The Ajax function is tight yo an event and not a global accessible function. So it cant be called directly

Comment: You can edit the JS code in the developer tools and call it directly, that's what I'm trying to tell you. You cannot trust in you JS code.